# How do I use Python to pack a big integer treating four characters as an unsigned long in network byte order as Ruby's .pack("N") does?

Tags: python, ruby, packing

This is the bit of Ruby I want to implement in Python:

```
Base64.urlsafe_encode64([Digest::MD5.hexdigest(url).to_i(16)].pack("N")).sub(/==\n?$/, '')
```

You see, this helps turn a URL like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

Into a small code like thise:

```
sUEBtw
```

The big integer that gets generated in the process is this:

```
307275247029202263937236026733300351415
```

I've been able to pack this into binary form using this Python code:

```
url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
n = int(hashlib.md5(url).hexdigest(), 16)                                       
s = struct.Struct('d')                                                          
values = [n]                                                                    
packed_data = s.pack(*values)                                                   
short_code = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(packed_data)[:-1]
print short_code
```

The short code I get is this:

```
zgMM62Hl7Ec
```

As you can see it's larger than the one I get with Ruby this the packing is using a different format.

You're help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you printed out the corresponding values to see where Python and Ruby diverge?

Comment: Is that big integer the md5 hash? I get that number 307275247029202263937236026733300351415 to be 39 digits (that's about 128 bits), so even representing each 8bits with a char, it is 16 chars, so some information is being lost. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you want to match Ruby's answer, you can simply take n % (2**32) and use struct(">I").

Comment: gbulmer: yes, that number is the md5 hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
import hashlib
import base64
url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
print base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hashlib.md5(url).digest()[-4:])[:-2]
```

#### Output

```
sUEBtw
```

`.digest()` gives the packed bytes of the full 16-byte digest so no need for `struct.pack`, but it seems Ruby's `.pack('N')` only converts the last four bytes of the digest.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby `pack('N')` converts to a network-order (big-endian) 32bit unsigned. python `struct('d')` converts to an IEEE double precision float.  I think you want `struct('>I')` for the equivalent [big endian 32 bit unsigned in python](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html).

Answer (score 0):

So it is clear now that Ruby's `pack('N')` takes only the lower 4 bytes so following [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm)'s suggestion I got this code to work:

```
import hashlib
import base64

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
n = int(hashlib.md5(url).hexdigest(), 16)                                       
s = struct.Struct('>I')                                                         
values = [n % (2**32)]                                                          
packed_data = s.pack(*values)                                                   
print base64.urlsafe_b64encode(packed_data)[:-2]
```

Nonetheless, as explained in [Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen)'s answer, `hashlib`'s HASH object's `digest()` method you get the hash already packed so taking the last four bytes with `[-4:]` for encoding using `Base64`'s `urlsafe_b64encode` is good enough.